# urllib2.urlopen failing while urllib.urlopen working on same URL

Tags: python, http, python-2.7, urllib2, urllib

I am trying to use urllib and urllib2 to scrape some data from a particular website.

Now the urllib was primarily for reading and processing the data while the code section with urllib2 was mainly for reading and storing the data.

The external site experienced some changes and while the urllib code section kept working the urllib2 section simply keeled over.

So I did some checks and noticed the urllib2.urlopen(URL) always returned a blank String while the urllib.urlopen(URL) always worked OK.

I dug deeper and enable debug logging on both urllib and urllib modules:

```
 >>> response2 =urllib2.urlopen('http://www.xxxxxxxxltd.com/web/guest/attendancelist')
send: 'GET /web/guest/attendancelist HTTP/1.1\r\nAccept-Encoding: identity\r\nHost: www.xxxxxxxxltd.com\r\nConnection: close\r\nUser-Agent: Python-urllib/2.6\r\n\r\n'
reply: 'HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily\r\n'
header: Server: nginx/0.7.67
header: Date: Thu, 28 Nov 2013 19:12:28 GMT
header: Transfer-Encoding: chunked
header: Connection: close
header: Location: http://www.xxxxxxxxplc.com/web/guest/attendancelist
send: 'GET /web/guest/attendancelist HTTP/1.1\r\nAccept-Encoding: identity\r\nHost: www.xxxxxxxxplc.com\r\nConnection: close\r\nUser-Agent: Python-urllib/2.6\r\n\r\n'
reply: 'HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently\r\n'
header: Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
header: Location: /home/new/attendancelist.jsp
header: Content-Length: 0
header: Date: Thu, 28 Nov 2013 19:12:26 GMT
header: Connection: close
send: 'GET /home/new/attendancelist.jsp HTTP/1.1\r\nAccept-Encoding: identity\r\nHost: www.xxxxxxxxplc.com\r\nConnection: close\r\nUser-Agent: Python-urllib/2.6\r\n\r\n'
reply: 'HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n'
header: Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
header: Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=F02B1F76CCCF6F41BE48951F6E1A6205; Path=/home
header: Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8
header: Content-Length: 0
header: Date: Thu, 28 Nov 2013 19:12:26 GMT
header: Connection: close
```

And....

```
>>> html3=urllib.urlopen('http://www.xxxxxxxxltd.com/web/guest/attendancelist')
send: 'GET /web/guest/attendancelist HTTP/1.0\r\nHost: www.xxxxxxxxltd.com\r\nUser-Agent: Python-urllib/1.17\r\n\r\n'
reply: 'HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily\r\n'
header: Server: nginx/0.7.67
header: Date: Thu, 28 Nov 2013 19:10:36 GMT
header: Connection: close
header: Location: http://www.xxxxxxxxplc.com/web/guest/attendancelist
send: 'GET /web/guest/attendancelist HTTP/1.0\r\nHost: www.xxxxxxxxplc.com\r\nUser-Agent: Python-urllib/1.17\r\n\r\n'
reply: 'HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently\r\n'
header: Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
header: Location: /home/new/attendancelist.jsp
header: Content-Length: 0
header: Date: Thu, 28 Nov 2013 19:10:34 GMT
header: Connection: close
send: 'GET /home/new/attendancelist.jsp HTTP/1.0\r\nHost: www.xxxxxxxxplc.com\r\nUser-Agent: Python-urllib/1.17\r\n\r\n'
reply: 'HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n'
header: Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
header: Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=8CFB903B80C42CA3DA37EDF90D84FF99; Path=/home
header: Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8
header: Date: Thu, 28 Nov 2013 19:10:35 GMT
header: Connection: close
```

As can be identified, the urllib2 connection flow has significantly more Connection headers ( one of which is the `Connection` header which has its value as `Close`).

Can anyone assist in finding why the urllib2 fails to retrieve the data while urllib module works well.

I am certain that it has something to do with the Connection headers but I want some sort of confirmation and thinking process explanation.

Thanks.

Comment: The only difference I see in log are `Accept-encoding` headers. What content is returned by urllib? p.ex. is it plain html or gziped?

Comment: The real problem is that while urllib returns the actual content of the page ( plain text properly scraped and formatted), the urllib2 response does not return any data whatsoever ( which is confirmed by the `Content-Length` value being set as 0 for the urllib2 header information.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest debugging using curl to replicate the headers the two versions of urllib are using. With a bit of trial and error you should be able to find the header causing the problem and go from there.

Comment: Thanks for the info and I will try it out. Do you have any links that would assist me in recreating the request using CURL? I am bit uncertain whether we would need something like the curl command line ( `wget` or something of that sort) or we could use a browser based solution ( such as `Fiddler`).